# AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to `Keras` and I was trying to build a `text-classification CNN` model using `Python 3.6` when I encountered this error :

```
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'name'
```

This is the code that I have written :

```
print("\nCreating Model...")
x1 = Input(shape=(seq_len1, 100), name='x1')
x2 = Input(shape=(seq_len2, 100), name='x2')
x1 = Reshape((seq_len1, embedding_dim, 1))(x1)
x2 = Reshape((seq_len2, embedding_dim, 1))(x2)

conv_0 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[0], 1), padding='valid', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')
conv_1 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[1], 1), padding='valid', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')
conv_2 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[2], 1), padding='valid', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')

maxpool = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 1), strides=(1,1), padding='valid')

output1 = conv_0(x1)
output1 = maxpool(output1)
output1 = conv_1(output1)
output1 = maxpool(output1)
output1 = conv_2(output1)
output1 = maxpool(output1)
.
.
# Same for output2
.
concatenated_tensor = Concatenate(axis=1)([output1, output2])
flatten = Flatten()(concatenated_tensor)
#dropout = Dropout(drop)(flatten)
output = Dense(units=1024, activation='relu')(flatten)
output = Dense(units=1024, activation='relu')(output)
output = Dense(units=1, activation='softmax')(output)

# this creates a model that includes
model = Model(inputs=[x1, x2], outputs=[output])
```

The error is encountered at last line. Please help me resolve this

**EDIT :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 91, in <module>
    model = Model(inputs=[x1, x2], outputs=[out])
  File "/../../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/../../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 91, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/../../anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 183, in _init_graph_network
    'The tensor that caused the issue was: ' +
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Can you add the trace, when does your code try to access the name? If you don't specify `name` argument it will not be set.

Comment: can you tell Keras version and os?

Comment: @L-- Keras version is : 2.2.0 and OS is : CentOS 7

Comment: @nuric I have added the trace.

Comment: The trace doesn't look complete, are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It is complete I have just replace the file path directories name with ".." rest it is same

Comment: @VatsalAggarwal Then where is the error you have mentioned in the stack trace?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

x1 and x2 point to the Reshape layers for the input and not the Input layers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The same error popped up for me when i used custom "swish" activation function.
I could resolve the same , with this code

```
class Swish(Activation):
    def __init__(self, activation, **kwargs):
        super(Swish, self).__init__(activation, **kwargs)
        self.__name__ = 'swish'
def swish(x,beta=1):
    return (x*sigmoid(x*beta))
get_custom_objects().update({'swish': Swish(swish)})
```